# PHP: What does ::class do?

Tags: php, class

I noticed in Laravel this syntax:

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class
```

What does the ::class operator do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from PHP doc 
"Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class. This is particularly useful with namespaced classes."

```
<?php
   namespace NS {

       class ClassName {

       }

       echo ClassName::class;
   }
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class):

> Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class. This is particularly useful with namespaced classes.

Comment: Hah, me too! I thought this would be the case, but after checking the docs now we both have confirmation.